# String Format Numbers Thousands 123K, Millions 123M, Billions 123B

Tags: c#, string-formatting

Is there a way using a string formatter to format Thousands, Millions, Billions to  123K, 123M, 123B without having to change code to divide value by Thousand, Million or Billion?

```
String.Format("{0:????}", LargeNumber)
```

Answer (score 90, accepted):

There are different ways to achieve this, but for me the easiest and quickest is to use [the "," custom specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#SpecifierTh)

```
double value = 1234567890;

// Displays 1,234,567,890   
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("#,#", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

// Displays 1,234,568K
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("#,##0,K", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

// Displays 1,235M
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("#,##0,,M", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

// Displays 1B
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("#,##0,,,B", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Comment: If I use it as "#,##0,,,.00B" It's rounding off the last decimal place, but I don't want it.

Comment: value.ToString("0,,,.#B", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) => 1.2B

Comment: any way to use this with currency?

Comment: What about Lakhs? how can i get it?

Answer (score 29):

I use this mix of formats in an **Extension Method** (just add it to your project and enjoy)

```
public static string ToKMB(this decimal num)
{
    if (num > 999999999 || num < -999999999 )
    {
        return num.ToString("0,,,.###B", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
    else
    if (num > 999999 || num < -999999 )
    {
        return num.ToString("0,,.##M", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
    else
    if (num > 999 || num < -999)
    {
        return num.ToString("0,.#K", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
    else
    {
        return num.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}
```

**Use:**

```
((decimal)235).ToKMB();
// 235

((decimal)1235).ToKMB();
// 1.2K

((decimal)6271235).ToKMB();
// 6.27M

((decimal)93246571235).ToKMB();
// 93.247B
```

> **Notes:**
>
> - It return more detail for bigger numbers and I like it.
> - It support negative numbers too. (Thanks to @Dusty for his note in comments.
> - I write a method for `decimal` numbers in this example, you can write some override methods for it to support `int`, `long` and `double` to use it without any casting such as:
>
>   `myIntNumber.ToKMB();`
>
>   `myLongNumber.ToKMB();`
>
>   `myDoubleNumber.ToKMB();`
>
>   `myDecimalNumber.ToKMB();`

Comment: What about Lakhs? how can i get it?

Comment: @ChandanKumar, do you mean a number like 100,000? My extension method (`((decimal)100000).ToKMB()`) returns this result for it: `100k`

Comment: It's worth noting that this covers a more complete use case if all of the `if` conditions also cover negatives ... e.g., `if(num > 999 || num < -999)`.

Answer (score 4):

You can implement a [ICustomFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icustomformatter.aspx) that divides the value by thousand, million or billion, and use it like this:

```
var result = string.Format(new MyCustomFormatter(), "{0:MyFormat}", number);
```

Comment: The implementation should be of both  ICustomFormatter and IFormatProvider interfaces