# String Format for Thousand separators

Tags: c#, string-formatting

Is there a way using String Formatter I can achieve the following:

$52,152 to $52.1

I have a series of values that are all thousands and I will like to display them in the above format.

Thanks

Comment: can you define the pattern ?

Comment: Are you working with Windows forms/WPF or ASP.NET?

Comment: @Renan:  Why does that matter?

Comment: @Shyju: Divide by 1000.

Comment: I want to use String.Format("")

Comment: Do you have those values as string or as a numeric data type?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx `,` scaling specifier

Comment: Why would it not be $52.2? (rounded to the nearest hundred)

Comment: @AustinSalonen because number formatting is most an UI thing. ASP.NET will usually deal with that automatically based on the language information of the user's browser. On WPF and Windows Forms, though, there are many ways a person may forcefully hard code one formatting or the other.

Comment: String type... I forgot to mention that.

Comment: You want **"$52,152"** as **"$52.1"** right (both strings)?

Comment: Look how I want from $52,152 (with comma) to $52.1 (with a period). Not sure if that is possible

Comment: Yes Alessandro, It has to have a period in it

Comment: If you're starting with an input string of `$52,152` - where is it coming from?  It may be more logical to do this conversion earlier in the chain...

Comment: Good reference : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731996/string-format-numbers-thousands-123k-millions-123m-billions-123b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for `$52.2`, using the [`,` number scaling specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx):

```
string.Format("{0:$0,.0}", 52152);
```

If you really want `52.1`, you’ll probably have to do it “manually”; sorry. All custom formatting strings seem to round.

Comment: Do you read @p.s.w.g question in OP comments? Also, there are more correct ways to achieve this result.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: Yes, I did read that question. And what in the world do you mean by “more correct”?

Comment: This led me to achieve the answer but I ended up using : {$0,.0}

Comment: For instance by setting `NumberFormatInfo`.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: you cannot scale numbers with a custom [`NumberFormatInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

In your case the non-formatted versions of your 2 numbers are inherently different

```
52152 != 52.1
```

A better solution might be to send the correct numbers to the UI but if not, you can use the `,` scaling specifier - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#SpecifierTh

```
void Main()
{
    decimal x = 52152M;

    var a = string.Format("{0:C}", x); //Current Format in Local Culture
    Console.WriteLine(a); //Prints €52,152.00

    var b = string.Format("${0:00000}", x); //Custom Format, no decimals
    Console.WriteLine(b);//Prints $52152

    var c = string.Format("${0:###,###,###}", x); //Custom Format, no decimals + 1000 seperators
    Console.WriteLine(c);//Prints $52,152

    var d = string.Format("${0:###,###,.0}", x); //Custom Format, 1 decimal place, 1000 seperators to support values over 1 million
    Console.WriteLine(d);//Prints $52.2

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
string input = "$52,152";
var number = long.Parse(input, NumberStyles.Currency);
string result = (number / 100L / 10m).ToString("C1");
```

Explanation. First division is an integer division that truncates. Second division is a `System.Decimal` division.

This assumes a culture (for example `new CultureInfo("en-US")`) where the currency sign is `"$"` and the thousands separator is `","`.