# String format numbers to millions, thousands with rounding

Tags: c#, .net, currency

I'm trying to format a price for display, and I want to display a number with the million (M) or thousands (K) suffix, but only ever display at most 3 values, rounded down.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731996/string-format-numbers-thousands-123k-millions-123m-billions-123b) which is very close to what I want, but doesn't handle rounding (specifically, always rounding down)

Likewise, [with this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134161/format-number-like-stack-overflow-rounded-to-thousands-with-k-suffix) you have no control over the rounding.

Sample input/expected output:

```
1 = 1
10 = 10
100 = 100
1000 = 1K
100000 = 100K
125000 = 125K
125900 = 125K
1000000 = 1M
1250000 = 1.25M
1258000 = 1.25M
10000000 = 10M
10500000 = 10.5M
100000000 = 100M
100100000 = 100M
```

I essentially only ever want to display 3 values.

I can't see how i can use the ["," custom specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.100).aspx#SpecifierTh) and specify rounding.

My initial thinking suggests I need to use a combination of the above, Math.Floor and some .ToString() formatting magic, but i'm not really sure where to start.

Can someone help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134161/format-number-like-stack-overflow-rounded-to-thousands-with-k-suffix

Comment: @Steve can't control rounding in that question

Comment: How I'm looking at it right now you would have to define some constant and have some conditional checking to verify is a number is between a certain range and then apply the correct "mapping" to display the value correctly.

Comment: @KevinAvignon yeah, definetely going to need some conditionals to see which range it falls into, but im stuck on figuring out how to do the rounding

Comment: It seems like the code in the link Steve posted always rounds up so if you -500 (or a number relative to the one you are trying to round on) from the number it will appear as though its rounding down, no?

Comment: @Rhexis - yep, nothing i've found has enabled me to control the rounding. That's why i feel like Math.Floor needs to play a part somehow.

Comment: The question I posted doesn't exactly match yours, but should be close enough to you to get a start. Also, Math.Round has an overload where you specify the rounding direction.

Comment: @Steve ive read the question, and alhough it provides some pointers, doesn't help with my rounding issue. Side note if something is "close enough" i don't think it should be closed as duplicate. Essentially, what i'm asking in this question has not been specifically been asked before on SO.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This should help, combined with one of the formatting techniques in the other questions you've linked to.

```
  internal long MaxThreeSignificantDigits(long x)
  {
     int i = (int)Math.Log10(x);
     i = Math.Max(0, i - 2);
     i = (int)Math.Pow(10, i);
     return x / i * i;
  }
```

EDIT:

OK, how about this?

```
 Console.WriteLine(SO30180672.FormatNumber(1));
 Console.WriteLine(SO30180672.FormatNumber(12));
 Console.WriteLine(SO30180672.FormatNumber(123));
 Console.WriteLine(SO30180672.FormatNumber(1234));
 Console.WriteLine(SO30180672.FormatNumber(12345));
 Console.WriteLine(SO30180672.FormatNumber(123456));
 Console.WriteLine(SO30180672.FormatNumber(1234567));
 Console.WriteLine(SO30180672.FormatNumber(12345678));
 Console.WriteLine(SO30180672.FormatNumber(123456789));
```

Following is partially copied from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23384710/253938

```
   internal class SO30180672
   {
      internal static string FormatNumber(long num)
      {
         num = MaxThreeSignificantDigits(num);

         if (num >= 100000000)
            return (num / 1000000D).ToString("0.#M");
         if (num >= 1000000)
            return (num / 1000000D).ToString("0.##M");
         if (num >= 100000)
            return (num / 1000D).ToString("0k");
         if (num >= 100000)
            return (num / 1000D).ToString("0.#k");
         if (num >= 1000)
            return (num / 1000D).ToString("0.##k");
         return num.ToString("#,0");
      }


      internal static long MaxThreeSignificantDigits(long x)
      {
         int i = (int)Math.Log10(x);
         i = Math.Max(0, i - 2);
         i = (int)Math.Pow(10, i);
         return x / i * i;
      }
   }
```

EDIT 2 - thank you very much to @Rhexis

```
   internal class SO30180672
   {
      internal static void RunTest()
      {
         Console.WriteLine(FormatNumber(1));
         Console.WriteLine(FormatNumber(10));
         Console.WriteLine(FormatNumber(100));
         Console.WriteLine(FormatNumber(1000));
         Console.WriteLine(FormatNumber(10000));
         Console.WriteLine(FormatNumber(100000));
         Console.WriteLine(FormatNumber(125000));
         Console.WriteLine(FormatNumber(125900));
         Console.WriteLine(FormatNumber(1000000));
         Console.WriteLine(FormatNumber(1250000));
         Console.WriteLine(FormatNumber(1258000));
         Console.WriteLine(FormatNumber(10000000));
         Console.WriteLine(FormatNumber(10500000));
         Console.WriteLine(FormatNumber(100000000));
         Console.WriteLine(FormatNumber(100100000));
      }

      private static string FormatNumber(long num)
      {
         // Ensure number has max 3 significant digits (no rounding up can happen)
         long i = (long)Math.Pow(10, (int)Math.Max(0, Math.Log10(num) - 2));
         num = num / i * i;

         if (num >= 1000000000)
            return (num / 1000000000D).ToString("0.##") + "B";
         if (num >= 1000000)
            return (num / 1000000D).ToString("0.##") + "M";
         if (num >= 1000)
            return (num / 1000D).ToString("0.##") + "K";

         return num.ToString("#,0");
      }
   }
```

Comment: Can you provide a bit more info, like how this can be combined with the other answers? Not sure how i can use this

Comment: I believe that @RenniePet has the answer. I do think though that you only need 3 if's in 'FormatNumber'. Using your code I got the desired output. (see here: http://pastebin.com/8qXHMvQG)

Comment: @Rhexis: Good idea. Can't be bothered changing my answer though - it was the bit about getting max 3 significant digits that caught my interest. I could remember learning how to do that long, long ago. (40 years ago, if you can believe that.)

Comment: @Rhexis: OK, now I've added your suggested improvement - thank you very much.

Comment: @RenniePet your code works with my tests, i'll go with this one. thanks!

Comment: How do I use this with decimal inputs? Math.Log10 doesn't take a decimal.

Answer (score 12):

This is my code with test outputs

```
1249            1.24K
12499           12.4K
124999          124K
1249999         1.24M
12499999        12.4M
124999999       124M
1249999999      1.24B
```

The code will output three digits at maximum.

```
    static string FormatNumber(uint n)
    {
        if (n < 1000)
            return n.ToString();

        if (n < 10000)
            return String.Format("{0:#,.##}K", n - 5);

        if (n < 100000)
            return String.Format("{0:#,.#}K", n - 50);

        if (n < 1000000)
            return String.Format("{0:#,.}K", n - 500);

        if (n < 10000000)
            return String.Format("{0:#,,.##}M", n - 5000);

        if (n < 100000000)
            return String.Format("{0:#,,.#}M", n - 50000);

        if (n < 1000000000)
            return String.Format("{0:#,,.}M", n - 500000);

        return String.Format("{0:#,,,.##}B", n - 5000000);
    }
```

Comment: Bravo - less than half the lines of code my answer contains.

Comment: very close... just need to round down. I think i need to take off 500 etc like @Rhexis mentioned above in order to round down

Comment: I need round up and your answer is simpler without using `Math.`

Answer (score 5):

Since the format essentially changes based on the range you'll most likely need some conditional formatting similar to below. I have only tested the sample set provided, so make sure this works for the full range of expected values.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(RoundAndFormat(1));
        Console.WriteLine(RoundAndFormat(10));
        Console.WriteLine(RoundAndFormat(100));
        Console.WriteLine(RoundAndFormat(1000));
        Console.WriteLine(RoundAndFormat(100000));
        Console.WriteLine(RoundAndFormat(125000));
        Console.WriteLine(RoundAndFormat(125900));
        Console.WriteLine(RoundAndFormat(1000000));
        Console.WriteLine(RoundAndFormat(1250000));
        Console.WriteLine(RoundAndFormat(1258000));
        Console.WriteLine(RoundAndFormat(10000000));
        Console.WriteLine(RoundAndFormat(10500000));
        Console.WriteLine(RoundAndFormat(100000000));
        Console.WriteLine(RoundAndFormat(100100000));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static String RoundAndFormat(Int32 value)
    {
        var result = String.Empty;
        var negative = value < 0;
        if (negative) value = value * -1;

        if (value < 1000)
        {
            result = value.ToString();
        }
        else if (value < 1000000)
        {
            result = RoundDown(value / 1000.0, 0) + "K";
        }
        else if (value < 100000000)
        {
            result = RoundDown(value / 1000000.0, 2) + "M";
        }
        else if (value < 10000000000)
        {
            result = RoundDown(value / 1000000.0, 0) + "M";
        }

        if (negative) return "-" + result;
        return result;
    }

    public static Double RoundDown(Double value, Int32 digits)
    {
        var pow = Math.Pow(10, digits);
        return Math.Truncate(value * pow) / pow;
    }
```

Comment: Made a quick change to handle negative values.

Comment: Shouldn't that be  Math.Truncate(value / pow) * pow;  ?

Comment: Nope, that function is a sig fig calculation. I am moving the decimal right x places, dropping the fractional portion, and moving the decimal back.
I'll use the example of 1.2580 with a count of 2 decimals:
pow = 10^2 = 100, 
Truncate(1.2580 * 100) = 125, 
125.80 / 100 = 1.25

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your help everyone, it got me on the right track to figuring it out myself.

```
public static string FormatPriceValue(this int num)
{
    if (num >= 100000000)
    {
        return ((num >= 10050000 ? num - 500000 : num) / 1000000D).ToString("#M");
    }
    if (num >= 10000000)
    {
        return ((num >= 10500000 ? num - 50000 : num) / 1000000D).ToString("0.#M");
    }
    if (num >= 1000000)
    {
        return ((num >= 1005000 ? num-5000 : num) / 1000000D).ToString("0.##M");
    }
    if (num >= 100000)
    {
        return ((num >= 100500 ? num - 500 : num) / 1000D).ToString("0.k");
    }
    if (num >= 10000)
    {
        return ((num >= 10550 ? num - 50 : num) / 1000D).ToString("0.#k");
    }

    return num >= 1000 ? ((num >= 1005 ? num - 5 : num) / 1000D).ToString("0.##k") : num.ToString("#,0");
}
```

Comment: Please take another look at the my answer, with improvements suggested by @Rhexis. Instead of thinking of "rounding" up or down, you should be thinking "max 3 significant digits". The code to do that is a bit cryptic, but once you have it there's no need for a lot of the "magic numbers" you're using - that's the kind of thing that often goes wrong when a program needs to be modified in the future.

Comment: @RenniePet i've got all these unit tests passing with my current code, so i'll plug yours in and see if they still pass. Stay tuned :)

Comment: That's great, glad I could help. But most of the honor should actually go to @Rhexis, I only did the significant digits part, it was Rhexis who fixed the formatting part.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I can't help but notice most of these answers are not far expandable, most of them are very similar lines of code repeated for more values. I needed something that worked on bigger values so instead of repetetive code I tried using math in a smart way. This does require using floating point math (doubles) as the maximum value of an unsigned long is only 1.84e+19. My solution:

```
public static string GetStringRepresentation(double count)
{
    string tokens = " KMBtqQsSondUDT"; //Infinitely expandable (at least to the limit of double floating point values)
    for (double i = 1; true; i += 1)
    {
        double val = Math.Pow(1000, i);
        if (val > count)
        {
            return $"{count / Math.Pow(1000, i - 1)}{tokens[(int)i - 1]}".Trim();
        }
    }
}
```

Test code:

```
Console.WriteLine("                     1: " + GetStringRepresentation(                  1).PadLeft(7, ' '));
Console.WriteLine("                    12: " + GetStringRepresentation(                 12).PadLeft(7, ' '));
Console.WriteLine("                   123: " + GetStringRepresentation(                123).PadLeft(7, ' '));
Console.WriteLine("                  1230: " + GetStringRepresentation(               1230).PadLeft(7, ' '));
Console.WriteLine("                 12340: " + GetStringRepresentation(              12340).PadLeft(7, ' '));
Console.WriteLine("                123450: " + GetStringRepresentation(             123450).PadLeft(7, ' '));
Console.WriteLine("               1230000: " + GetStringRepresentation(            1230000).PadLeft(7, ' '));
Console.WriteLine("              12340000: " + GetStringRepresentation(           12340000).PadLeft(7, ' '));
Console.WriteLine("             123450000: " + GetStringRepresentation(          123450000).PadLeft(7, ' '));
Console.WriteLine("            1230000000: " + GetStringRepresentation(         1230000000).PadLeft(7, ' '));
Console.WriteLine("         1230000000000: " + GetStringRepresentation(      1230000000000).PadLeft(7, ' '));
Console.WriteLine("      1230000000000000: " + GetStringRepresentation(   1230000000000000).PadLeft(7, ' '));
Console.WriteLine("   1230000000000000000: " + GetStringRepresentation(1230000000000000000).PadLeft(7, ' '));
```

Output:

```
                     1:       1
                    12:      12
                   123:     123
                  1230:   1,23K
                 12340:  12,34K
                123450: 123,45K
               1230000:   1,23M
              12340000:  12,34M
             123450000: 123,45M
            1230000000:   1,23B
         1230000000000:   1,23t
      1230000000000000:   1,23q
   1230000000000000000:   1,23Q
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a VBS/VbScript Function to do that.
NB => VB and VBA offer direct format call.

' Usage: Return a number using it's greatert thousand symbol (ex: 234,789,145 = 234.8M)

Function Format_Large_Number(nb, nbDigit)

```
' Safety
If Not IsNumeric(nb) Then FormatLargeNumber = nb : Exit Function
If nbDigit < 1 Then nbDigit = 1
If nbDigit > 3 Then nbDigit = 3

' Initiate var
Dim rtnNb    : rtnNb    = nb
Dim nbFormat : nbFormat = FormatCurrency(rtnNb, 0, vbTrue, vbTrue)
               nbFormat = Trim(Replace(nbFormat, "$", ""))
Dim nbSymbol : nbSymbol = ""
Dim nbDecRnd : nbDecRnd = ""
Dim arrNb    : arrNb    = Split(nbFormat, " ")

' Asign symbol
Select Case UBound(arrNb)
    Case 0
        nbSymbol = ""   ' Hundred
    Case 1
        nbSymbol = "K"  ' Thousand
    Case 2
        nbSymbol = "M"  ' Million
    Case 3
        nbSymbol = "G"  ' Billion
    Case 4
        nbSymbol = "T"  ' Trillion
    Case 5
        nbSymbol = "P"  ' Quadrillion
    Case 6
        nbSymbol = "E"  ' Quintillion
End Select

' Concatenate rtn string
If Ubound(arrNb) > 0 Then
    If nbDigit < 3 Then
        If CInt(arrNb(1)) > 499 Then
            nbDecRnd = CStr(CInt(Left(arrNb(1),nbDigit)) + 1) ' Ceil decimal rtn
        Else
            nbDecRnd = Left(arrNb(1),nbDigit)
        End If
    Else
        nbDecRnd = Left(arrNb(1),nbDigit)
    End If
    
    rtnNb = arrNb(0) & "," & nbDecRnd & nbSymbol    ' All others
Else
    
    rtnNb = arrNb(0) & nbSymbol                     ' Hundred
End If

' Rtn value
Format_Large_Number = rtnNb
```

End Function