# Is there a readable way to put millions into c# code?

Tags: c#, coding-style

This is a little hard to read:

```
int x = 100000000;
```

Is there an easy way to write:

```
int x = 100,000,000;
```

So that the scale is obvious?

> Please note this is NOT about formatting the output.

Comment: If not duplicate then related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11731996/961113

Comment: This is NOT about formatting for output

Comment: Side remark: be careful adding magic numbers in your code. Many times they need to be configurable instead of compiled into the code.

Comment: int t = 1000 * 1000;

Comment: Its basically related, rules of declaring variables.. so i think we have know already.. what variables are and their properties before entring into programming..

Comment: @GrantWinney According to an answer below, the numerical literal format is now being proposed for C# 7!

Answer (score 12):

Starting with C#7 you will be able to use the underscore-char (`_`) to seperate digit groups. The underscore can be placed anywhere in a number. A simple example:

```
const int MILLION = 1_000_000;
```

You can place the `_` anywhere you want and can even combine it with integer literals:

```
const int USHORT_MAX = 0xFF_FF;
```

Or even with floats and decimals, even after the decimal sign:

```
const decimal SMALL_VALUE = 0.000_000_001;
```

Comment: Damn, that feature slipped.  Last year it was supposed to be a part of C# 6. See at the end of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn683793.aspx

Comment: darn... they cut a few nice features... I weep for the auto-property initializers

Comment: @crazy_crank, Auto-Property initializers are there in C# 6.0 (https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Languages-features-in-C%23-6-and-VB-14) right ?

Comment: ok, either they put that in again, or I've completely missinterpreted something here...

Comment: @crazy_crank - C#7 will include digit separators. It is shipped with the VS 15 Preview.

Answer (score 6):

> Is there any easy way to write `100,000,000`

**No. It is not possible to put commas in numeric.**

Comma and other similar things are for presentation purpose. If you are worried about code readability then either declare constants with name like `MILLION`, `TEN_MILLIONS` etc or simply **name the variable to represent value**.

Comment: Please check @crazy_crank answer. You can use `_` as commas in a number. The compiler will ignore `_`.

Comment: @hpaknia, at the time, this answer was written, C#7 didn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

If the purpose is to help the reader understand the code, then code comments may be appropriate, e.g.

```
int number = 1000000; //1,000,000
```

If you think scientific notation is easier to read, you could try

```
int number = 1 * 10^6;
```

or

```
int number = (int) 1E+6;
```

Constants like this are computed at compile time and do not affect performance.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't have commas in your `int` declarations. Probably the best thing to add something like this at the beginning of your code:

`const int oneMillion = 1000000;`

Then just set `int x = oneMillion;`

If you'd like `int y` to equal 2 million, then just set `int y = 2 * oneMillion;`

That's best practice (in my experience).

Does that help?

---

**EDIT:**

For more elaborate integers, you can try something like this:

```
const int thousand = 1000;
const int million = 1000000;

int x = 1 * million
           + 233 * thousand
           + 456;
```

It's not the prettiest, but perhaps it suits your readability needs. It also doesn't affect performance nearly as much as `Int32.Parse("100,000,000");`

Comment: I need the flexiblity to specify funny amounts: 1,233,456

Comment: Ah, I see. I'd probably use `Int32.Parse` then. See @Chris Steele's answer and see if that works for you.

Comment: I'd probably drop the "one" from those variable names so it would read better.

Answer (score 1):

```
int x = Int32.Parse("100,000,000", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Number);
```

Whether or not that's more readable is a personal preference, I suppose.

Comment: I think this answers the posted question directly and to the point.

Comment: It's a pretty silly thing to do, though.  If performance isn't an issue at all then sure, this approach would "work" (for certain values of "work").  But it also moves a fairly significant potential for errors from compile-time to run-time.  Which is kind of a bad thing.  It solves the "problem", I'll give you that.  But I think the OP is just trading a small problem today for a large problem tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own class for your number, something like this.

```
public class MyNumber
{
    long? _myValue = null;

    public MyNumber(string amount)
    {
        long result = 0;
        if (long.TryParse(amount.Replace(",", ""), out result))
        {
            _myValue = result;
        }
        else
            _myValue = 0;
    }

    public bool HasValue()
    {
        if (_myValue.HasValue) return true;
        return false;
    }

    public long Value()
    {
        if (this.HasValue())
        {
            return _myValue.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you could call it like this.

```
        MyNumber myValue = new MyNumber("9,999,100");

        if (myValue.HasValue())
            MessageBox.Show("Value Is " + myValue.Value().ToString());
```

Comment: This is a far worse form of the answer that suggests using `Int32.Parse`.

Comment: I was just answering the question, not suggesting that any way is better than the other. And for your information the Int32.Parse statement above generates a format exception because it can't handle commas.

Comment: Yep, you are right, I forgot the NumberStyles.Number in there to get it to parse punctuation.  I'll fix it.