# How can I customize the Int format in C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I can't find a way to customize the format, example `555.555 to $ 555.55 K` or `4201337 to $ 4.20 M`.

I've used CultureInfo but I can't find the solution.

On the Microsoft website I haven't found the solution: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings

What could be the most correct solution to this problem? Thanks!

Comment: take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488796/does-net-provide-an-easy-way-convert-bytes-to-kb-mb-gb-etc which is similar or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731996/string-format-numbers-thousands-123k-millions-123m-billions-123b i think....

Comment: also why is 555.555 to $ 555.55 K ?

Comment: Context matters.  How do you need  to use it?  Where will this formatting be needed?  Can you show us the code where this would be used?

Comment: Sorry! This question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731996/string-format-numbers-thousands-123k-millions-123m-billions-123b has solved my problem.I'm developing a mobile video game and I wanted to format the player's fictitious money so that it would be correctly displayed on screen.